# back_insert_iterator with remove_copy_if

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

I am trying to use a `back_insert_iterator` with `remove_copy_if` using vectors but I have compile errors.

Do you know why the code below is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

struct checkRem : std::unary_function<int,bool> {
    int _val;
    checkRem( int val ): _val(val){}
    bool operator()(int aVal){ return aVal > _val;}
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
int _vIn[] = {1,2,3,4,2,3,4,3,6,7};
std::vector< int > vIn( _vIn, _vIn + (sizeof( _vIn )/sizeof(_vIn[0])));

// remove with copy
std::vector<int>vOut;
std::back_insert_iterator< std::vector<int> >  bit( vOut );

std::vector< int >::iterator new_end = 
std::remove_copy_if(
    vIn.begin(),
    vIn.end(),
    bit,
    checkRem(2)
);
}
back_insrt_iter.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
back_insrt_iter.cpp:30: error: conversion from      
‘std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >’ to non-scalar  
type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >’ 
requested
```

Comment: Would you mind pasting real code? So that we can find the error easier? what the heck is `std::vectorvrc;`

Comment: and WTH is `std::back_insert_iterator >  bit( vrc );` too :)

Comment: Could you please paste a complete example - with the definition of checkFoo vr and all the includes? Nothing seems to be wrong in here

Comment: If you view the vote counts, it's +0/-1, yet the question net vote is +1. Anybody else see this?

Comment: @Kiril: It's the same as you'd get from std::back_inserter(vrc).

Comment: Hi all! Example code is now complete and correct.

Comment: @Roger - Argh, I see, after the correcting of the code. What bothered me was this `>` after the `back_inserter_iterator`. 10x, anyway

Comment: Only today I realized that it is possible to put the C++ code as it is provided that each line begins with a TAB. I used to insert a block of code between <pre> and </pre> and each time it is a pain for the < character( idem for the > ).

Answer (score 1):

`std::remove_copy_if()` returns an iterator of the same type as the output iterator. In this case, it's a `std::back_inserter_iterator`. You're not changing the input container, but you're copying into an output container the elements for which the predicate doesn't hold.

In short, use `std::remove_if()` if you want to change your input container.

Comment: You are right! In this specific case I just removed the code "std::vector< int >::iterator new_end = " so that it doesn't return any value and it is fine. Thanks a lot! AFG